# 2.2GB JSON file parses inconsistently

Tags: python, json, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to decode a large utf-8 json file (2.2 GB). I load the file like so:

```
f = codecs.open('output.json', encoding='utf-8')
data = f.read()
```

If I try to do any of: `json.load`, `json.loads` or `json.JSONDecoder().raw_decode` I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-fc2255017b19> in <module>()
----> 1 j = jd.decode(data)

/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
    367         end = _w(s, end).end()
    368         if end != len(s):
--> 369             raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
    370         return obj
    371

ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column -2065998994 - line 1 column 2228968302
    (char -2065998994 - 2228968302)
```

`uname -m` shows `x86_64` and

```
> python -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'
('7fffffffffffffff', True)`
```

so I should be on 64 bit and the integer size shouldn't be a problem.

However, if I run:

```
jd = json.JSONDecoder()
len(data) # 2228968302
j = jd.raw_decode(data)
j[1] # 2228968302
```

The second value in the tuple returned by `raw_decode` is the end of the string, so `raw_decode` seems to parse the entire file with seemingly no garbage at the end.

So, is there something I should be doing differently with the json? Is the `raw_decode` actually decoding the entire file? Why is `json.load(s)` failing?

Comment: What kind of system are you running on?  2.2 billion is too large for a signed 32-bit integer, and the negative numbers in the exception detail suggest you're running into problems with that.

Comment: Without looking at the underlying code, I'm going to guess that the functions convert the input to a string, and that they have overflow issues trying to handle a string of that size. The "raw" version presumably does not, and thus is able to parse the whole thing.

Comment: @TimPeters I added this to my question but I am on a 64 bit architecture.

Comment: @Gabe This might be possible but it is not a problem to load the entire file into memory through file.read so should it be a problem inside of the json module?

Comment: OK, that helps :-)  Note that `raw_decode()` "can be used to decode a JSON document from a string that may have extraneous data at the end".  So if there really is garbage following the JSON object, it's no surprise that `raw_decode()` can parse it but other methods cannot.  Although, yup, I see that `raw_decode()` says the object ended at 2228968302.  So it's a mystery to me too! ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters Yes but the index returned from raw_decode which indicates the end of the document decoded is the last index of the string.

Comment: What are the actual types of `s` and `end`?  Are they really full `int64` types (e.g. regular Python `int`s) or some narrower 32-bit integer type?

Comment: @MrFooz I just ran a debugger: s is unicode and end is int.

Answer (score 10):

I'd add this as a comment, but the formatting capabilities in comments are too limited.

Staring at the source code,

```
raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
```

calls this function:

```
def errmsg(msg, doc, pos, end=None):
    ...
    fmt = '{0}: line {1} column {2} - line {3} column {4} (char {5} - {6})'
    return fmt.format(msg, lineno, colno, endlineno, endcolno, pos, end)
```

The `(char {5} - {6})` part of the format is this part of the error message you showed:

```
(char -2065998994 - 2228968302)
```

So, in `errmsg()`, `pos` is -2065998994 and `end` is 2228968302.  Behold! ;-):

```
>>> pos = -2065998994
>>> end = 2228968302
>>> 2**32 + pos
2228968302L
>>> 2**32 + pos == end
True
```

That is, `pos` and `end` are "really" the same.  Back from where `errmsg()` was called, that means `end` and `len(s)` are really the same too - but `end` is being viewed as a 32-bit signed integer.  `end` in turn comes from a regular expression match object's `end()` method.

So the real problem here appears to be a 32-bit limitation/assumption in the regexp engine.  I encourage you to [open a bug report](http://bugs.python.org/)!

Later:  to answer your questions, yes, `raw_decode()` is decoding the entire file.  The other methods **call** `raw_decode()`, but add the (failing!) sanity checks afterwards.